# J meter Load Testing , Performance Testing

Tags: performance, jmeter, load

Does J meter Suits for Desktop application and Windows applications Does it suits for load and performance testing

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do a load test on desktop application (i'm assuming he desktop application acts as a client for a web service or a database), If so it makes sense to  consider load-testing back-end by simulating a situation where hundreds of desktop applications are simultaneously accessing the back end server.